# Is there a PowerShell command that can move files between two folders in an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

What is the PowerShell command for moving all files from folder A to folder B in an S3 bucket?

Comment: No move command that I could find, it's copy and remove old

Comment: I tried this in PowerShell console:
Copy-S3Objetc -BucketName "mybucket/folderA" -DestinationBucket "mybucket/folderB" | Remove-S3Object -Bucket
.......It did not work.
It is asking for Keys and stuck in the console.

Comment: The folders are not objects but created in the UI as visual help. A file with key/name "folder/file.ext" is added to a folder, rename/copy it to "folder2/file.ext" and there will be a new folder.

Comment: Guessing something like Get-S3Object -BucketName "mybucket" -Prefix "folderA/" | % { Copy-S3Object -Key $_.Key -DestinationKey $($_.Key).Replace('folderA','folderB') } Might have to add -BucketName and -DestinationBucket for Copy (don't have anything in my aws to try). If it works with a test, add ; Remove-S3Object -Key $_.Key to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3 mv --recursive s3://my-bucket/folderA/ s3://my-bucket/folderB/
```

It will perform a `CopyObject` and a `DeleteObject` object for each object in `folderA`.

Comment: I'm using an existing PowerShell script. This is something I'd like to incorporate into an existing script. I believe I can not use the AWS CLI command in an existing PowerShell script...right?

Comment: If the AWS CLI is installed, then you can call the AWS CLI from PowerShell. Otherwise, you can use `Copy-S3Object` and `Remove-S3Object` from [AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/).

Answer (score 0):

Move files from "folder" folderA to folderB in same bucket

```
Get-S3Object -BucketName "mybucket" -Prefix "folderA/" | % { Copy-S3Object -BucketName "mybucket" -Key $_.Key -DestinationKey $($_.Key).Replace('folderA','folderB'); Remove-S3Object -BucketName "mybucket" -Key $_.Key -Force }
```

To create an "empty folder" with only a / -named file, use this command. It will also be moved with the rest of the files if not excluded.

```
Write-S3Object -BucketName mybucket -Key "folderA/" -Content "."
```

Comment: Saw now that you are useing a script, so a oneliner might not be needed, so assigning to variables and logging the work might be better :)

Comment: Your script is deleting folderA.  I wanted to move all of the files from folder A to folder B....it is moving the files, but it is also deleting folder A (which I do not want).  ...can it be fixed ?

Comment: As said before, there is nothing like folders. Create a file with name/key "folderA/dummy" and you will have a folder. Any file with "folderA/subfolderA/file" will create folders in the UI, but no objects that can be worked with. USER THIS FOR A DUMMY FILE: Write-S3Object -BucketName mybucket -Key "folderA/dummy" -Content "."

Comment: Oh, there can be files called just "folderA/" that will be a folder. My mistake. Write-S3Object -BucketName mybucket -Key "folderA/" -Content "."

Comment: Confused..... Write-S3Object is to be used instead of Copy-S3Object or Get-S3Object ?  It will give more clarity if you please put the full command

Comment: I have edited the answer. Write-S3Object is used to upload or write a file. In this case to create a file for the folder to be visible in the UI. Copy-S3Object could also be used with: Copy-S3Object -BucketName "mybucket" -Key "folderB/" -DestinationKey "folderA/"

Comment: Is there still something unclear, or is this the answers?